# Expression of a Lagrangian in other form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

I'm reading Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum field theory and standard model and some question arises

In his book, p.133, he says that

Any vector field can be written as

$$ A_{\mu}(x) = A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x)\tag{8.109}$$
with
$$ \partial_{\mu} A^{T}_{\mu}=0.\tag{8.110}$$

And he saids that "Start with the most general Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian for a vector field $A_{\mu}$:

$$\mathcal{L} = aA_{\mu}\square A_{\mu} + bA_{\mu}\partial{\mu}\partial{\nu}A{\nu}+m^{2} A^{2}_{\mu}.\tag{8.111}$$

Then, performing our substitution and using Eq. $ \partial_{\mu} A^{T}_{\mu}=0$ gives

$$ \mathcal{L} = aA^{T}_{\mu} \square A^{T}_{\mu} + m^{2}(A^{T}_{\mu})^{2}-(a+b)\pi \square^{2}\pi - m^{2} \pi \square \pi.\tag{8.112}$$

Q. My question is, why this final result is true?

If we substitute $ A_{\mu}(x) = A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x)$ in $\mathcal{L} = aA_{\mu}\square A_{\mu} + bA_{\mu}\partial{\mu}\partial{\nu}A{\nu}+m^{2} A^{2}_{\mu}$, then we obtain

$$\mathcal{L}= a(A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x)) \square (A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x)) + b(A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x))\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}(A^{T}_{\nu}(x)+ \partial_{\nu}\pi(x))+m^{2}(A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x))(A^{T}_{\mu}(x)+ \partial_{\mu}\pi(x)) $$
$$ = aA^{T}_{\mu}\square A^{T}_{\mu} + aA^{T}_{\mu}\square \partial_{\mu} \pi + a\partial_{\mu}\pi \square A^{T}_{\mu} + a\partial_{\mu}\pi \square (\partial_{\mu} \pi)
 + b[A^{T}_{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}A^{T}_{\nu} + A^{T}_{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}(\partial_{\nu} \pi) + (\partial_{\mu} \pi)(\partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} A^{T}_{\nu}) +  
(\partial_{\mu} \pi)(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} (\partial_{\nu}\pi))]
 + m^{2}[(A^{T}_{\mu})^{2} + A^{T}_{\mu}(\partial_{\mu} \pi) + (\partial_{\mu}\pi)A^{T}_{\mu} + 
(\partial_{\mu}\pi)(\partial_{\mu}\pi)]  $$

and then we may use $ \partial_{\mu} A^{T}_{\mu}=0$.

And this is a point that I stuck. How can we make further progress?

My question originates from following page (p.133) in the Schwartz's book:

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use are so-called null-Lagrangians, i.e. terms that are a divergence and can be dropped in the Lagrangian because in the action integral they only contribute a surface term, or, to put it differently, their variational derivative vanishes.

For example,
$$
A_\mu^T \square \partial_\mu \pi = \partial_\mu\left(A_\mu^T\square\pi\right) - \partial_\mu A_\mu^T \square\pi\,,
$$
wherein on the right-hand side the second term is zero through the gauge condition and the first is a null-Lagrangian and can be dropped. Applying this technique in other terms as well does yield the desired result.

Comment: Yes. It seems that I finally reached the desired formula. Thank you for pointing out technique~.