# Integration by parts on generic tensors

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, integration, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I try to rephrase here a my question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4661784/), explaining more specifically the case.

Given a lagrangian $L=L(\theta_{\mu\nu},\phi)$ ,  the conserved Noether current is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
j_{\beta}^{\alpha} \doteq - \dfrac{\partial L^{(2)}}{\partial (\partial_{\alpha}\theta_{\mu\nu})}\partial_{\beta}\theta_{\mu\nu} - \dfrac{\partial L^{(2)}}{\partial (\partial_{\alpha}\phi)}\partial_{\beta}\phi + \delta_{\beta}^{\alpha} L^{(2)} 
\end{equation}

where $L^{(2)}$ is $L$ at second order in the fields (but this is not important for my question).  For a scalar-tensor theory of gravity, one finds something like

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
j_{\beta}^{\alpha} = \dfrac{\phi_{0}}{32 \pi G} \left[ - 2 \partial^{\nu} \theta^{\mu \alpha} \partial_{\beta}\theta_{\mu\nu} + \partial^{\alpha} \theta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\beta}\theta_{\mu\nu} +   ...   + \delta_{\beta}^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu} \theta_{\mu\gamma} \partial^{\gamma} \theta_{\mu\nu}   + ...     \right]
\end{equation}
I'm pretty sure about this result but, again, this is  not important to my question. What is important is that the authors of the paper  say that they integrate by parts some terms in (2), in order to exploit the gauge conditions and the field equations for $\phi$ and $\theta_{\mu\nu}$, and so to cancel some terms. The first term, for example, becomes $2 \theta^{\mu\alpha}\partial_{\beta}\partial^{\nu} \theta_{\mu\nu}$ and so on. Ok, if I do this, I actually get the same result as them. My question is **why this is possible**:  I  can't integrate (by parts) any tensor (or pieces of it) and neglect border terms; it would be like saying that $ln(x)=-1$ (I have integrated by parts the rhs)  !

---

Comment: Why don't you heed the advice on mathematics.SE to give a concrete example so that we can see your partial integration in action?

Comment: Without further context I would be wary about partial integration in (2), but it may be possible. You can perform partial integration in the action functional, or, equivalently, use so-called null-Lagrangians, cf. my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719309/expression-of-a-lagrangian-in-other-form/719315#719315

Comment: As I said in your previous question, you need to provide further context to make the question meaningful. For example, maybe they were being sloppy and they meant to say they integrate by parts in the action, which produces a different current. Or perhaps they mean they're adding something like Belinfante improvement terms which do affect the Noether currents but do not affect the Noether charges.

Comment: @kricheli I know that one can  integrate by parts the lagrangian terms, but $j_{\beta}^{\alpha}$ is not a lagrangian, is just a tensor defined as in (1).

Comment: @knzhou The context is just the computation of the pseudotensor of scalar-tensor theory of gravity. The paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.08863v1.pdf (eq.81).  The authors simply start from the action of Brans-Dicke theory, compute the second order lagrangin $L^{(2)}$ and then use eq. (1) above. Nothing else. They need $j_{\beta}^{\alpha}$ to obtain the gravitational pseudotensor

Comment: @gravitone123 Of course a Noether current is not a Lagrangian, I was trying to imply that you might want to try partial integration in the Lagrangian to obtain a different Noether current derived from the Lagrangian. ;)

Comment: That context totally answer the question though. This is a standard thing in linearized gravity: the stress-energy tensor is not gauge invariant, so one considers a spacetime averaged stress-energy tensor. (That's what the brackets in the neighboring equations mean.) Because there is an implicit spacetime integral, you can approximately integrate by parts. This should be covered in most good GR textbooks.

Comment: @knzhou Sorry for forgetting to link the paper. However, you answer is not clear to me. What do you mean for " Because there is an implicit spacetime integral, you can approximately integrate by parts " ? Do this imply that border terms are always negligible (i.e. for **any** $\Omega$) in this context ? Sorry again

Comment: No, it means that for typical field profiles with typical wavelength $\lambda$ and a region of size $d \gg \lambda$, the boundary term is suppressed by $\sim \lambda/d$. It is not a mathematically rigorous statement that holds for any weird field profile.

Comment: But again -- this is a totally standard thing and you can see extended explanations in any textbook (Carroll, Wald, MTW, Maggiore, etc.)